# How to make Vuetify compatible with IE in CDN

Tags: internet-explorer, com, vuetify.js, compatibility, cdn

i want make Vuetify compatible with IE in my CDN website.
This is my code(with PHP):

```html
    <v-app>
    <div>
   <v-btn>Dont work in IE</v-btn>
    </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch&flags=gated"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
})
  </script>
```

But, polyfill dont word, c## Heading ##an you help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the [official doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/browser-support/#ie-11-amp-safari-9-support) and it says we need to use `babel-polyfill` to support Vuetify in IE 11. The CDN url of `babel-polyfill` is `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.4/polyfill.js`. We can include it in the first one `<script>` tags. Then it can work well in IE 11.

The sample code is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app>
            <v-main>
                <v-container>Hello world</v-container>
            </v-main>
        </v-app>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.4/polyfill.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference link: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill